# Markov chain transition probabilities

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose that we have a markov chain $\left\{X_{n}\right\}$ and we also have $Y_{n}=(X_{n-1},X_{n})$ which is also a markov chain.And I would like to find the transition probabilities for $Y_{n}$.

So the probabilities that I search for would be  $\mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1}=(X_{n},X_{n+1})|Y_{n}=(X_{n-1},X_{n}))$

Is it true that $\mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1}=(X_{n},X_{n+1})|Y_{n}=(X_{n-1},X_{n}))=p(X_{n-1},X_{n})p(X_{n},X_{n+1})$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation is kind of a mess, which is why you're confused. You want to compute

$$P(Y_{n+1}=(x_2,y_2) \mid Y_n=(x_1,y_1)).$$

Expressed entirely in terms of the chain $X_n$, this is

$$P(X_{n+1}=y_2,X_n=x_2 \mid X_{n-1}=x_1,X_n=y_1).$$

Obviously this is zero if $x_2 \neq y_1$. Otherwise, because $X_n$ is Markov, the condition on $X_{n-1}$ is irrelevant and the whole thing reduces to

$$P(X_{n+1}=y_2 \mid X_n=y_1).$$

Comment: Thank you , indeed I was really confused with the notation that I had in mind.So we can write the $P(Y_{n+1}=(x_2,y_2) \mid Y_n=(x_1,y_1))$ as $\delta_{x_{2}y_{1}}p(y_{1},y_{2})$ right ??

Comment: @Jonathan1234 Yep, that's right.